# how create json type for java Map interface in entity

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have this field

```
   @Type(type = "json")
@Column(columnDefinition = "json")
private Map<String, String> businessHours;
```

and this is on top of my class

```
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)//this is error
})
```

and this is migartion

```
 alter table properties alter column business_houres type json USING business_hours::json;
```

but it can't understand JsonType it is red

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `JsonBinaryType.class` or `JsonStringType.class` for the type `json` and `JsonType.class` is not a type that comes out of the box.

```
@TypeDefs({
  @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class BaseEntity {
   @Type(type = "json")
   @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
   private BusinessHours businessHours;
}
```

You can create a wrapper class that stores the businessHours as follows:

```
public class BusinessHours implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, String> businessHours; 
}
```

Comment: I agree but after set some map and then save it gives me this error.  ERROR: column "business_hours" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: @JackNickelson I have updated my answer can you see if using the wrapper class with `JsonBinaryType.class` solves your question?

Comment: I don't need binary it has ordering but now i set String one but after setting some map and saving it it gives this error  ERROR: column "business_hours" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7836833/deepakchethan

Comment: @JackNickelson can you try with creating `BusinessHours.java` with the map instead and see if that helps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7836833/deepakchethan       no it gave order which i don't need

Comment: Maybe it's the map losing its order. Can you confirm if order is right before the db save by logging and if not use `LinkedHashMap` instead?

Comment: yes it is right I'm sure

Comment: I saw it from dubug